# Ansible conditional when list items not in path string

Tags: python, ansible

I need to perform and Ansible task on a list of files, but only if the file path doesn't contain elements from another list.

I have a list var defined in my playbook. These are files and directories that I would like to exclude from the task. I collected the files object earlier in the playbook with `ansible.builtin.find` and now I have a list of JSON objects. I want to skip the task on any of these objects where any of the elements from `exclude` are in the filepath of the item being iterated over. Options are limited because some of the list items in `exclude` are filenames and some are directory names, so I can't use a filepath module to only select the filename.

```
exclude:
  - README.md
  - .git
  - .gitlab
  - .gitignore
```

But I don't know how to do this in a clean way. This is the task in question

```
- name: Replace some text in files if their path doesn't contain any items from "exclude"
  ansible.builtin.replace:
    path: "{{ item.path }}"
    regexp: "Version1"
    replace: "Version2"
  with_items: files.files
  when: "(exclude|items) not in (item.path | from_json)"
```

Is there a way that I can make this work? Do I need an entirely different approach, or does ansible have the ability to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution. Posting here in case anyone comes across this.

```
- name: Replace some text in files if their path does not contain any items from "exclude"
  ansible.builtin.replace:
    path: "{{ item.path }}"
    regexp: "Version1"
    replace: "Version2"
  with_items: "{{ (files).files }}"
  when: "item.path| split('/')| intersect(exclude)| length == 0"
```